# Calling EJB from WAR outside the EAR inside one WAS

Tags: java, maven, websphere, java1.4

My project structure will be like this:

->WebSphere Application Server (WAS)

----->EAR

-------->EJB Modules

-------->EJB Client

----->WAR

-------->Web Service Server

how can i call or use the EJB from that WAR?

i tried this before to call EJB when the war is inside the ear:

```
public SomeEJBServiceClassBusiness getBusinessClass() throws RemoteException {

    SomeEJBServiceClassBusiness SomeEJBServiceClassBusiness = null;
    try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:rir:/NameServiceServerRoot");
        Context context = new InitialContext(env);

        SomeEJBServiceClassHome remoteObject = (SomeEJBServiceClassHome) getRemoteObject(context, SomeEJBServiceClassHome.class.getName());
        SomeEJBServiceClassBusiness = remoteObject.create();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("Error getting EJB " + SomeEJBServiceClassHome.class.getName());
    } catch (CreateException e) {
        LOG.error("Error creating EJB " + SomeEJBServiceClassHome.class.getName());
    }
    return SomeEJBServiceClassBusiness;
}

public Object getRemoteObject(Context ctx, String jndiName) throws NamingException {
    Object obj;
    StringBuffer fullJndiName;
    try {
        fullJndiName = new StringBuffer();
        fullJndiName.append("java:comp/env/").append(jndiName);
        LOG.debug("Trying connect to [" + fullJndiName.toString() + "]");
        obj = ctx.lookup(fullJndiName.toString());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        try {
            fullJndiName = new StringBuffer();
            fullJndiName.append("java:comp/").append(jndiName);
            LOG.debug("Trying connect to [" + fullJndiName.toString() + "]");
            obj = ctx.lookup(fullJndiName.toString());
        } catch (NamingException e0) {
            try {
                fullJndiName = new StringBuffer();
                fullJndiName.append(jndiName);
                LOG.debug("Trying connect to [" + fullJndiName.toString() + "]");
                obj = ctx.lookup(fullJndiName.toString());
            } catch (NamingException e1) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But now when i need the WAR to be moved to outside the EAR this doesn't work anymore. Because i need to copy one JAR(from inside the EAR) with EJBHome and EJBBusiness as a library for my WAR. is there a way for a WAR application to use EJB inside EAR(different application) without copying any jar?

Comment: What does not work for you? what exception are you getting?

Comment: sory, i edited my question. because if i copy it, each time i update that jar inside the EAR, i must duplicate it to my WAR lib.

Comment: that's expected behavior. Each time you provide a new EJB implementation (in case of significant changes) you also have to change EJB client jar

Comment: yeah in case of method signature change, but you will only need to change one jar, not two EJBClient.jar :) (because i need those jar inside EAR and WAR for now, and thats what i need to avoid)